# How can I find all possibly paths in undirected graph using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix, graph

Let's take as an example that we have such numpy matrix:

```
[[ 0  3  5 0]
 [ 3  0  2 9]
 [ 5  2  0 7]
 [ 0  9  7 0]]
```

I would like to find all possible paths from 0 to 3. I want the solution to be neutral. I will always go from 0 to the latest index of the matrix. In this case 3. Maybe there is already a ready algorithm or someone can show own solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `networkx`. It is a package for graph theory for python.

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
A=np.matrix([[ 0,  3,  5, 0],
             [ 3,  0,  2, 9],
             [ 5,  2,  0, 7],
             [ 0,  9,  7, 0]])
G=nx.from_numpy_matrix(A)

print(nx.shortest_path(G,source=0,target=3)) # shortest path
# Result
# [0, 1, 3]

print(list(nx.all_simple_paths(G,source=0,target=3))) # all simple paths
# Result
# [[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 3], [0, 2, 1, 3], [0, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: But there is also a path 0,2,3 or 0,2,1,3 or 0,1,2,3 am I right?

Comment: sorry, in my mind was only shortest path. I updated the answer.

Comment: Yes, I used `for path in nx.all_simple_paths(G,source=0,target=14):
    print(path)`

Comment: Do you have an idea how can I reach the target with the greatest possibly value using only one path?

Comment: The graphs are the representation of some markov decision process? or where are you getting the probabilities?

Comment: If it's a simple softmax equation between the edges of the graph, I think that the shortest path should be the answer for the higher probability. But you need some time to verify that in theory with the proper equations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159515/discussion-between-john-smith-and-silgon).